Infinitely many zeros of an elementary real function with zeros the twin probable primes?
Related to Are there open problems for primes which are known for probable primes?
Define the probable primes $p$ to be integers $p>1$,
which satisfy $2^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$.
The probable primes are the primes and a small set of composite
integers.
Let $f(x):=\sin(\pi x)^2+\sin(\pi \frac{2^{x-1}-1}{x})^2$ for real $x \ne 0$.
The real zeros of $f(x)$ are $1$ and the probable primes.
$\sin(\pi x)=0$ iff $x$ is integer and the sum of
the squares of two reals is zero iff both terms are zero.
Wolfram Alpha finds series
for $f(x)$.
Define $g(x):=f(x)^2+f(x+2)^2$.
The zeros of $g(x)$ are the smaller twin of twin probable primes $(p,p+2)$.
Both $f,g$ are elementary real functions.

Q1 Does $g(x)$ has infinitely many zeros?

It is tempting to ask are there infinitely many
prime triples $(p,p+2,p+4)$.  The answer is negative,
since one of the three numbers is divisible by $3$,
despite $g_2(x)=f(x)^2+f(x+2)^2+f(x+4)^2$ is similar to $g(x)$.


Merry Christmas to those who celebrate it.

So, it's just twin - prime + Carmichael numbers.

So you're just asking if there are infinitely many twin probable primes? Any reason you obfuscate the question by using this function instead of just asking this outright?

@AlapanDas These are not quite Carmichael numbers - they only need to be Fermat pseudoprimes to base $2$, not all coprime bases.

@Wojowu Oh yes. Thanks for correcting me.

@Wojowu Isn't it clear that we are asking about specific attack with elementary function on a more general problem?

@joro No, it's not clear. What more general problem do you have in mind? And do you have any reason to believe using those elementary functions will be helpful?

@Wojowu Are you competent enough to tell which elementary functions have infinitely many solutions?

@joro No, no one is, by Richardson's theorem that's an undecidable problem. Which is part of why I don't think translating your problem into this language is likely to be helpful.

@Wojowu You have some valid points, but I don't completely agree with you. Worst case hardness doesn't imply hardness of solution to special cases. Unfortunately the problem is hard, so probably this reduction is really hopeless.
